# MapReduce algorithm for Binary Tree in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, reverse-engineering

Using MIPS to implement a `mapreduce` function that uses the MapReduce approach to analyze a set of strings. The strings to be processed are stored in a full binary tree. In this tree, each leaf contains a pointer to a string. Every non-leaf node of the tree contains pointers to two children.

The function `mapreduce` should return an integer whose value is the result of applying the map function and then the reduce function to the given tree. The function takes three arguments:

- A pointer to the root of the binary tree containing the strings to be processed. This pointer will never be null.
- A pointer to a map function.
- A pointer to a reduce function.

There will be a few map and reduce functions. All the map functions take a pointer to a null-terminated ASCII string and return an integer. You'll need to call the functions by pointer(`jalr`)

- `unit` always returns 1, regardless of the argument.
- `strlen` returns the length of the argument string.
- `sum` returns the sum of two arguments.
- `min` returns the smaller of the two arguments.
- `max` returns the larger of the two arguments.

```
mapreduce:
    # substitute your implementation here
    li $v0, 0
    jr $ra


strlen: 
    li $v0, 0
strlen_top:
    lbu $t0, 0($a0)
    beqz $t0, strlen_done
    addi $v0, $v0, 1
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    b strlen_top
strlen_done:
    jr $ra

unit:
    li $v0, 1
    jr $ra

sum:    
    add $v0, $a0, $a1
    jr $ra

min:
    slt $t0, $a0, $a1
    beqz $t0, min_a1
    move $v0, $a0
    jr $ra
min_a1: move $v0, $a1
    jr $ra

max:
    slt $t0, $a1, $a0
    beqz $t0, max_a1
    move $v0, $a0
    jr $ra
max_a1: move $v0, $a1
    jr $ra

main:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    # mapreduce(tiny,unit,sum) = 4
    la $a0, tiny
    la $a1, unit
    la $a2, sum
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(lorem,unit,sum) = 64
    la $a0, lorem
    la $a1, unit
    la $a2, sum
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(tiny,unit,min) = 1
    la $a0, tiny
    la $a1, unit
    la $a2, min
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(lorem,unit,min) = 1
    la $a0, lorem
    la $a1, unit
    la $a2, min
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(tiny,unit,max) = 1
    la $a0, tiny
    la $a1, unit
    la $a2, max
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(lorem,unit,max) = 1
    la $a0, lorem
    la $a1, unit
    la $a2, max
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(tiny,strlen,sum) = 16
    la $a0, tiny
    la $a1, strlen
    la $a2, sum
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(lorem,strlen,sum) = 354
    la $a0, lorem
    la $a1, strlen
    la $a2, sum
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(tiny,strlen,min) = 3
    la $a0, tiny
    la $a1, strlen
    la $a2, min
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(lorem,strlen,min) = 2
    la $a0, lorem
    la $a1, strlen
    la $a2, min
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(tiny,strlen,max) = 5
    la $a0, tiny
    la $a1, strlen
    la $a2, max
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int

    # mapreduce(lorem,strlen,max) = 13
    la $a0, lorem
    la $a1, strlen
    la $a2, max
    jal mapreduce
    move $a0, $v0
    jal print_int
    
    # return
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


print_int:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    jal print_newline
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

print_string:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    jal print_newline
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
    
print_newline:
    li $v0, 11
    li $a0, 10
    syscall
    jr $ra

    
.data
    
tiny:    .word 0 tinyL tinyR
tinyL:   .word 0 tinyLL tinyLR
tinyR:   .word 0 tinyRL tinyRR
tinyLL:  .word 1 tinyLL_str
tinyLR:  .word 1 tinyLR_str
tinyRL:  .word 1 tinyRL_str
tinyRR:  .word 1 tinyRR_str
tinyLL_str:  .asciiz "itty"
tinyLR_str:  .asciiz "bitty"
tinyRL_str:  .asciiz "word"
tinyRR_str:  .asciiz "set"

lorem:   .word 0 loremL loremR
loremL:  .word 0 loremLL loremLR
loremR:  .word 0 loremRL loremRR
loremLL:     .word 0 loremLLL loremLLR
loremLR:     .word 0 loremLRL loremLRR
loremRL:     .word 0 loremRLL loremRLR
loremRR:     .word 0 loremRRL loremRRR
loremLLL:    .word 0 loremLLLL loremLLLR
loremLLR:    .word 0 loremLLRL loremLLRR
loremLRL:    .word 0 loremLRLL loremLRLR
loremLRR:    .word 0 loremLRRL loremLRRR
loremRLL:    .word 0 loremRLLL loremRLLR
loremRLR:    .word 0 loremRLRL loremRLRR
loremRRL:    .word 0 loremRRLL loremRRLR
loremRRR:    .word 0 loremRRRL loremRRRR
loremLLLL:   .word 0 loremLLLLL loremLLLLR
loremLLLR:   .word 0 loremLLLRL loremLLLRR
loremLLRL:   .word 0 loremLLRLL loremLLRLR
loremLLRR:   .word 0 loremLLRRL loremLLRRR
loremLRLL:   .word 0 loremLRLLL loremLRLLR
loremLRLR:   .word 0 loremLRLRL loremLRLRR
loremLRRL:   .word 0 loremLRRLL loremLRRLR
loremLRRR:   .word 0 loremLRRRL loremLRRRR
loremRLLL:   .word 0 loremRLLLL loremRLLLR
loremRLLR:   .word 0 loremRLLRL loremRLLRR
loremRLRL:   .word 0 loremRLRLL loremRLRLR
loremRLRR:   .word 0 loremRLRRL loremRLRRR
loremRRLL:   .word 0 loremRRLLL loremRRLLR
loremRRLR:   .word 0 loremRRLRL loremRRLRR
loremRRRL:   .word 0 loremRRRLL loremRRRLR
loremRRRR:   .word 0 loremRRRRL loremRRRRR
loremLLLLL:  .word 0 loremLLLLLL loremLLLLLR
loremLLLLR:  .word 0 loremLLLLRL loremLLLLRR
loremLLLRL:  .word 0 loremLLLRLL loremLLLRLR
loremLLLRR:  .word 0 loremLLLRRL loremLLLRRR
loremLLRLL:  .word 0 loremLLRLLL loremLLRLLR
loremLLRLR:  .word 0 loremLLRLRL loremLLRLRR
loremLLRRL:  .word 0 loremLLRRLL loremLLRRLR
loremLLRRR:  .word 0 loremLLRRRL loremLLRRRR
loremLRLLL:  .word 0 loremLRLLLL loremLRLLLR
loremLRLLR:  .word 0 loremLRLLRL loremLRLLRR
loremLRLRL:  .word 0 loremLRLRLL loremLRLRLR
loremLRLRR:  .word 0 loremLRLRRL loremLRLRRR
loremLRRLL:  .word 0 loremLRRLLL loremLRRLLR
loremLRRLR:  .word 0 loremLRRLRL loremLRRLRR
loremLRRRL:  .word 0 loremLRRRLL loremLRRRLR
loremLRRRR:  .word 0 loremLRRRRL loremLRRRRR
loremRLLLL:  .word 0 loremRLLLLL loremRLLLLR
loremRLLLR:  .word 0 loremRLLLRL loremRLLLRR
loremRLLRL:  .word 0 loremRLLRLL loremRLLRLR
loremRLLRR:  .word 0 loremRLLRRL loremRLLRRR
loremRLRLL:  .word 0 loremRLRLLL loremRLRLLR
loremRLRLR:  .word 0 loremRLRLRL loremRLRLRR
loremRLRRL:  .word 0 loremRLRRLL loremRLRRLR
loremRLRRR:  .word 0 loremRLRRRL loremRLRRRR
loremRRLLL:  .word 0 loremRRLLLL loremRRLLLR
loremRRLLR:  .word 0 loremRRLLRL loremRRLLRR
loremRRLRL:  .word 0 loremRRLRLL loremRRLRLR
loremRRLRR:  .word 0 loremRRLRRL loremRRLRRR
loremRRRLL:  .word 0 loremRRRLLL loremRRRLLR
loremRRRLR:  .word 0 loremRRRLRL loremRRRLRR
loremRRRRL:  .word 0 loremRRRRLL loremRRRRLR
loremRRRRR:  .word 0 loremRRRRRL loremRRRRRR
loremLLLLLL:     .word 1 loremLLLLLL_str
loremLLLLLR:     .word 1 loremLLLLLR_str
loremLLLLRL:     .word 1 loremLLLLRL_str
loremLLLLRR:     .word 1 loremLLLLRR_str
loremLLLRLL:     .word 1 loremLLLRLL_str
loremLLLRLR:     .word 1 loremLLLRLR_str
loremLLLRRL:     .word 1 loremLLLRRL_str
loremLLLRRR:     .word 1 loremLLLRRR_str
loremLLRLLL:     .word 1 loremLLRLLL_str
loremLLRLLR:     .word 1 loremLLRLLR_str
loremLLRLRL:     .word 1 loremLLRLRL_str
loremLLRLRR:     .word 1 loremLLRLRR_str
loremLLRRLL:     .word 1 loremLLRRLL_str
loremLLRRLR:     .word 1 loremLLRRLR_str
loremLLRRRL:     .word 1 loremLLRRRL_str
loremLLRRRR:     .word 1 loremLLRRRR_str
loremLRLLLL:     .word 1 loremLRLLLL_str
loremLRLLLR:     .word 1 loremLRLLLR_str
loremLRLLRL:     .word 1 loremLRLLRL_str
loremLRLLRR:     .word 1 loremLRLLRR_str
loremLRLRLL:     .word 1 loremLRLRLL_str
loremLRLRLR:     .word 1 loremLRLRLR_str
loremLRLRRL:     .word 1 loremLRLRRL_str
loremLRLRRR:     .word 1 loremLRLRRR_str
loremLRRLLL:     .word 1 loremLRRLLL_str
loremLRRLLR:     .word 1 loremLRRLLR_str
loremLRRLRL:     .word 1 loremLRRLRL_str
loremLRRLRR:     .word 1 loremLRRLRR_str
loremLRRRLL:     .word 1 loremLRRRLL_str
loremLRRRLR:     .word 1 loremLRRRLR_str
loremLRRRRL:     .word 1 loremLRRRRL_str
loremLRRRRR:     .word 1 loremLRRRRR_str
loremRLLLLL:     .word 1 loremRLLLLL_str
loremRLLLLR:     .word 1 loremRLLLLR_str
loremRLLLRL:     .word 1 loremRLLLRL_str
loremRLLLRR:     .word 1 loremRLLLRR_str
loremRLLRLL:     .word 1 loremRLLRLL_str
loremRLLRLR:     .word 1 loremRLLRLR_str
loremRLLRRL:     .word 1 loremRLLRRL_str
loremRLLRRR:     .word 1 loremRLLRRR_str
loremRLRLLL:     .word 1 loremRLRLLL_str
loremRLRLLR:     .word 1 loremRLRLLR_str
loremRLRLRL:     .word 1 loremRLRLRL_str
loremRLRLRR:     .word 1 loremRLRLRR_str
loremRLRRLL:     .word 1 loremRLRRLL_str
loremRLRRLR:     .word 1 loremRLRRLR_str
loremRLRRRL:     .word 1 loremRLRRRL_str
loremRLRRRR:     .word 1 loremRLRRRR_str
loremRRLLLL:     .word 1 loremRRLLLL_str
loremRRLLLR:     .word 1 loremRRLLLR_str
loremRRLLRL:     .word 1 loremRRLLRL_str
loremRRLLRR:     .word 1 loremRRLLRR_str
loremRRLRLL:     .word 1 loremRRLRLL_str
loremRRLRLR:     .word 1 loremRRLRLR_str
loremRRLRRL:     .word 1 loremRRLRRL_str
loremRRLRRR:     .word 1 loremRRLRRR_str
loremRRRLLL:     .word 1 loremRRRLLL_str
loremRRRLLR:     .word 1 loremRRRLLR_str
loremRRRLRL:     .word 1 loremRRRLRL_str
loremRRRLRR:     .word 1 loremRRRLRR_str
loremRRRRLL:     .word 1 loremRRRRLL_str
loremRRRRLR:     .word 1 loremRRRRLR_str
loremRRRRRL:     .word 1 loremRRRRRL_str
loremRRRRRR:     .word 1 loremRRRRRR_str
loremLLLLLL_str:     .asciiz "Lorem"
loremLLLLLR_str:     .asciiz "ipsum"
loremLLLLRL_str:     .asciiz "dolor"
loremLLLLRR_str:     .asciiz "sit"
loremLLLRLL_str:     .asciiz "amet,"
loremLLLRLR_str:     .asciiz "consectetur"
loremLLLRRL_str:     .asciiz "adipiscing"
loremLLLRRR_str:     .asciiz "elit,"
loremLLRLLL_str:     .asciiz "sed"
loremLLRLLR_str:     .asciiz "do"
loremLLRLRL_str:     .asciiz "eiusmod"
loremLLRLRR_str:     .asciiz "tempor"
loremLLRRLL_str:     .asciiz "incididunt"
loremLLRRLR_str:     .asciiz "ut"
loremLLRRRL_str:     .asciiz "labore"
loremLLRRRR_str:     .asciiz "et"
loremLRLLLL_str:     .asciiz "dolore"
loremLRLLLR_str:     .asciiz "magna"
loremLRLLRL_str:     .asciiz "aliqua."
loremLRLLRR_str:     .asciiz "Ut"
loremLRLRLL_str:     .asciiz "enim"
loremLRLRLR_str:     .asciiz "ad"
loremLRLRRL_str:     .asciiz "minim"
loremLRLRRR_str:     .asciiz "veniam,"
loremLRRLLL_str:     .asciiz "quis"
loremLRRLLR_str:     .asciiz "nostrud"
loremLRRLRL_str:     .asciiz "exercitation"
loremLRRLRR_str:     .asciiz "ullamco"
loremLRRRLL_str:     .asciiz "laboris"
loremLRRRLR_str:     .asciiz "nisi"
loremLRRRRL_str:     .asciiz "ut"
loremLRRRRR_str:     .asciiz "aliquip"
loremRLLLLL_str:     .asciiz "ex"
loremRLLLLR_str:     .asciiz "ea"
loremRLLLRL_str:     .asciiz "commodo"
loremRLLLRR_str:     .asciiz "consequat."
loremRLLRLL_str:     .asciiz "Duis"
loremRLLRLR_str:     .asciiz "aute"
loremRLLRRL_str:     .asciiz "irure"
loremRLLRRR_str:     .asciiz "dolor"
loremRLRLLL_str:     .asciiz "in"
loremRLRLLR_str:     .asciiz "reprehenderit"
loremRLRLRL_str:     .asciiz "in"
loremRLRLRR_str:     .asciiz "voluptate"
loremRLRRLL_str:     .asciiz "velit"
loremRLRRLR_str:     .asciiz "esse"
loremRLRRRL_str:     .asciiz "cillum"
loremRLRRRR_str:     .asciiz "dolore"
loremRRLLLL_str:     .asciiz "eu"
loremRRLLLR_str:     .asciiz "fugiat"
loremRRLLRL_str:     .asciiz "nulla"
loremRRLLRR_str:     .asciiz "pariatur."
loremRRLRLL_str:     .asciiz "Excepteur"
loremRRLRLR_str:     .asciiz "sint"
loremRRLRRL_str:     .asciiz "occaecat"
loremRRLRRR_str:     .asciiz "cupidatat"
loremRRRLLL_str:     .asciiz "non"
loremRRRLLR_str:     .asciiz "proident,"
loremRRRLRL_str:     .asciiz "sunt"
loremRRRLRR_str:     .asciiz "in"
loremRRRRLL_str:     .asciiz "culpa"
loremRRRRLR_str:     .asciiz "qui"
loremRRRRRL_str:     .asciiz "officia"
loremRRRRRR_str:     .asciiz "deserunt"
```

What is the signature of the map function, reduce function, and mapreduce function?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like homework.

Comment: @karlphillip: [To close, or not to close, that is the homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404004) - "homework" isn't a close reason.  It doesn't matter whether it's homework, it matters whether it's too-broad or whatever other reason.

Comment: @karlphillip, as I see it, the homework assignment is to write the `mapreduce` function implementation in assembly, while the post asks a specific question about some details in the assignment, so I feel it is answerable without doing someone's homework.

Comment: @ErikEidt I have no issues with other people taking the time to explain some random guy's homework to him/her.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the signature of the map function?

The map functions are `unit` and `strlen`.  They can both be called via function pointer as:

```
int (*map) (char *)
```

(`unit()` won't look at the parameter).

How do we know this?  By analysis of the assembly code for those two functions, which is to say their register usages, in particular `$a0`, `$a1`, and `$v0`.  Both function set `$v0` prior to return so this appears as a return value; both function place an integer into `$v0`, so, looks like `int` type, though could have been `unsigned int`.  Neither function uses `$a1`, but one uses `$a0` as a pointer that is dereferenced to obtain an `char` (albeit an unsigned char so that'd be a better type).

---

> What is the signature of the reduce function?

The reduce functions are `sum`, `min`, and `max`, and can be called via function pointer as:

```
int (*reduce) (int, int)
```

How do we know this?  Again, by analysis of the assembly code for these functions.  All three functions access `$a0` and `$a1`, so looks like two parameters — they all access these parameters as if integer, and they all return an integer in `$v0`.

---

> The function `mapreduce` should return an integer whose value is the result of applying the map function and then the reduce function to the given tree. The function takes three arguments:
>
> - A pointer to the root of the binary tree containing the strings to be processed.
> - A pointer to a map function.
> - A pointer to a reduce function.

This makes

```
    int mapreduce ( 
                    Tree *node,               // A pointer to binary tree
                    int (*map) (char *),      // A pointer to a map function
                    int (*reduce) (int, int)  // A pointer to a reduce function
                  )
```

---

That given test `main` does the following calls, among others, as tests:

`mapreduce(tiny,unit,sum)` expecting 4 as the answer.

`mapreduce(lorem,strlen,min)` expecting 2 as the answer.

---

While we are at it, let's also give the types needed to express `Tree`, which can be:

```
enum TreeType { Branch, Leaf }; // Branch is 0, Leaf is 1

struct Tree;

struct LeafNode {
    TreeType tag;
    char *leafString;
};

struct BranchNode {
    TreeType tag;
    Tree *leftChild;
    Tree *rightChild;
};

struct Tree {
    union {
        TreeType tag;
        LeafNode leafNode;
        BranchNode branchNode;
    };
};
```

Here's a function that accepts a `Tree` pointer as a parameter, shown to illustrate how the `Tree` would be manipulated in C:

```
void printTreeNode ( Tree *p ) {
    // test the tag to see if Leaf or Branch
    if ( p->tag == Leaf ) {
        // print the string
        printf("%s\n", p->leafNode.leafString); 
    }
    else {
        // print the pointer addresses for the children
        printf("%p,%p\n", p->branchNode.leftChild, p->branchNode.rightChild);
    }
}
```

---

Given these types and signatures, you can work out the `mapreduce` algorithm in C, if you like, then take it to assembly.

Function calling in an assembly language like MIPS is a complex topic involving lots of subtle issues, regarding following the calling convention to pass parameters and return values, preservation of values so as to survive a function call, and also calling via function pointers, which is actually fairly simple if you already have the rest.

When you get to making the function in assembly, you're going to want to have the algorithm already working (best in C but pseudo code ok) so you can focus solely on the assembly implementation of a working algorithm.  Much better to write assembly when you already know what you're trying to make the function do.

(The alternative is trying to think in assembly language you don't know to develop an algorithm you also don't know — that is a huge and potentially unsurmountable problem.  So, an approach to addressing this level of difficulty is to decompose the problem in those two parts: (a) algorithm in language you know and (b) assembly implementation of that.)

The `mapreduce` function can be recursive, since it will traverse a recursive data structure (the tree), that would make sense.  Recursion, while sounding scary, adds no complexity to a function's implementation over doing ordinary (i.e. non-recursive) function calling (as long as there is a recursion supporting call stack, and MIPS has one).  This will be about 4-6 lines of C code.

(Alternatively, one could do an iterative version to avoid the recursion, but function calling of `map` and `reduce` already require calling conventions to be observed, so eliminating recursion by using iteration won't really simplify the problem, in fact it will complicated things, because a temporary stacking data structure would be needed.)